# Need to display a hidden div and have it stay when the user hovers over it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

I am trying to recreate the same effect as this page http://www.zendesk.com/company/management-team

I am using the code below

```
 $("#theLink").hover(
    function () {
        $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

which is half of what I was looking for, you can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/np87e/.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it function that way. How can I make it so it functions the same as on zendesk?

Comment: glad that our answers helped you out; be sure to select the answer you went with, and up-vote any you found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/np87e/405/

You could just put the div inside the `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="theLink">hover here
<div id="theDiv">this is the div</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. With that and a bit of CSS I was able to make it function exactly as I wanted, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with pure css:

```
#theDiv {
    display: none;
}
#theLink:hover + #theDiv, #theDiv:hover {
    display: inherit;
}
```

However, that relies on specific positioning of your elements in the DOM (namely, as siblings), similar to @superUntitled's answer (the pseudo-popup must be a child).

Though it doesn't get you out of having to have the pseudo-popup appear (to the user) next to the element you want to transition from, you can do something like the following to disentangle the elements' positions in the DOM:

```
#theDiv {
    display: none;
}
#theDiv.hovering, #theDiv:hover {
    display: inherit;
}
// ... wherever your script lives
$('#theLink').hover(function(){
 $('#theDiv').addClass('hovering');
},function(){
 $('#theDiv').removeClass('hovering');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating your own plugin?

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tooltip = function (options) {
        var settings = options;
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).hover(

            function () {
                $(settings.div).stop().fadeIn();
            },

            function () {
                $(settings.div).stop().fadeOut();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

//USAGE
$("#theLink").tooltip({
    div: "#theDiv"
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/np87e/406/)